# Why the scope goes wrong in this Typescript/jscript piece of code

Tags: javascript, typescript

the code below is inside a "view" and is having scope issues with "this"

Typescript:

```
getInvitations() {
        var invitationsUri = "/Api/Invitations/";

        $.ajax({
            url: invitationsUri ,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        })
            .done((result) => {
                $.each(result, (index, item) => {
                    var invitation = new Invitation();
                    invitation.InvitationId(item.InvitationId);
                    invitation.Invited(true);
                    invitation.Email(item.Email);

                    this.Business.Invitations.push(invitation);
                });
            })
            .fail((x, y, z) => {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z + ' - failed to get invitations');
            });
    }

    getUsers() {
        var usersUri = "/Api/Users/";

        $.ajax({
            url: usersUri,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        })
            .done((result) => {
                $.each(result, (index, item) => {
                    var user = new User();
                    user.Id(item.Id);
                    user.UserName(item.UserName);
                    user.Email(item.Email);

                    this.Business.Users.push(user);
                });
            })
            .fail((x, y, z) => {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z + ' - failed to get users');
            });
    }
```

The first method works well, the second thinks "this" is referring to "item", so it does not recognize "Business" as a property and with that the objective is not achieved.

Any ideas what could be happening here?

EDIT:
Here is the generated code (jscript)

```
BusinessView.prototype.getInvitations = function () {
        var _this = this;
        var invitationsUri = "/Api/Invitations/";

        $.ajax({
            url: invitationsUri,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).done(function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                var invitation = new Invitation();
                invitation.InvitationId(item.InvitationId);
                invitation.Invited(true);
                invitation.Email(item.Email);

                _this.Business.Invitations.push(invitation);
            });
        }).fail(function (x, y, z) {
            alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z + ' - failed to get invitations');
        });
    };

    BusinessView.prototype.getUsers = function () {
        var _this = this;
        var usersUri = "/Api/Users/";

        $.ajax({
            url: usersUri,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).done(function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                var user = new User();
                user.Id(item.Id);
                user.UserName(item.UserName);
                user.Email(item.Email);

                _this.Business.Users.push(user);
            });
        }).fail(function (x, y, z) {
            alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z + ' - failed to get users');
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a jQuery `.each()` callback, `this` is always set by jQuery so it won't be what `this` was in a higher level scope.  If you need to access the value of `this` from the higher level scope, then the usual work-around is to save it to a local variable at that higher level scope and you can then access that local variable from within the `.each()` callback function.

From the code snippet you included in your answer, it is not clear what `this` value you want to access.  You may also need to know that call a regular function such as calling `getInvitations()` will change the `this` pointer to point to either the global object or in strict mode to `undefined`.  `this` is set by the javascript interpreter on every function call based on how the function call is made.

Comment: Sample code.... This is Typescript with Knockout, and for what ever reason the getInvitations work just fine.

Comment: @Oakcool - So, is the `$.each()` you're using from jQuery or Knockout?

Comment: @Oakcool - OK, then my explanation stands.  `$.each()` set `this` inside the callback.  It won't be what it was at a higher scope.  You will need to use the work-around I suggested.

Comment: Technically its done, if you look at the generated code you will see.

 BusinessView.prototype.getUsers = function () {
        var _this = this;

Answer (score 0):

You got the lambda correct in the each calls i.e. `$.each(result, (index, item) => {` You should do the same for the function definitions to ensure that `this` gets scoped correct all the way through i.e. `getInvitations = () => {` and `getUsers = () => {`